# SwiftUI "Use of unresolved identifier" after renaming default contentView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have created a new project in Xcode and attempted to rename the default `contentView` file to  `LandmarkDetail`.

I have renamed ContentView.swift to LandmarkDetail.swift, updated the name of the `contentView` struct and updated 'SceneDelegate.swift' with the new view name. My code is as follows:

LandmarkDetail.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .frame(height: 300)

            CircleImage()
                .offset(y: -130)
                .padding(.bottom, -130)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Turtle Rock")
                    .font(.title)
                HStack {
                    Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("California")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkDetail()
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialised and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: LandmarkDetail())
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

...
```

However, the build is failing with `Use of unresolved identifier 'LandmarkDetail'` error in SceneDelegate.swift. I have replaced all occurrences of `contentView` but suspect I am missing updating something else as my LandmarkDetail view is not being found.

I have tried doing a clean build incase something was being cached. And I haven't been able to find any mention of needing to add imports or changes elsewhere to make LandmarkDetail callable from the SceneDelegate class.

Comment: Try cleaning the build, and rebuilding

Comment: Think I used the wrong keyboard shortcut when trying to clean the build initially. Doh! Anyway the combination of cleaning the build and removing the DerivedData file has my build running again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the future always rename classes by cmd+clicking on the class name then click "Rename...". This automatically finds all the references to the class and renames them for you, so you don't accidentally miss one.

[image: Rename Class]

But even after that you're right, cleaning the build and removing derivedData if that doesn't work should resolve any remaining errors.